# How to import sql file to database ignoring X lines in file?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import pretty large .sql file to mysql database. However After some time of importing it, I encountered an error, so I want to fix it, and continue importing from the specific line of this file (when I ended last time), is this possible?

Comment: Are you meaning `--force` option?

Comment: What's the error? And how do you import?

Comment: The error is "Duplicate entry 'X' for PRIMARY_KEY, but this is not so important, I'm asking here about importing really, not an error.

Comment: If you are on a unix like system you can use tail to get lines after a specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time you can try to import mysql file with `-f` to ignore the errors:

```
-f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29) along with the [MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) if you are on a unix like system like Himanshu mentioned. The command would be:

```
tail -n +100 dump.sql | mysql -u user -p -D database
```

Note: You may run into problems starting part of the way thru a file because there may be references to values set at a previous point in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IGNORE number LINES` syntax to do this:

The `IGNORE number LINES` option can be used to ignore lines at the start of the file. For example, you can use `IGNORE 1 LINES` to skip over an initial header line containing column names:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**See also:**

- [**`LOAD DATA INFILE`** Syntax in official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: But this is for loading data into table only, or I'm wrong? I'm talking about executing .sql file.

Comment: Yes, but this is the only functionality that is similar to what you need