# Execute .sql file from certain line

Tags: mysql, linux

When importing large database from a file
( mysql -u root -p database_name < file.sql )
I lost the connection when the big part of job was done. I got the error:
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 55314064: MySQL server has gone away

So I'd like to restart this job from the line 55314064 and not beginning from the begin of file.
How can I do it? ( Centos 7, Mysql 8.01)
Thank you

EDIT:
I tried this idea
mysql -u root -p < tail -n +55314064 file.sql
But it didn't work : No such file or directory
Probably I can solve it (not very elegant) outputting tail to another file...

UPDATE:
I don't know why this question was closed.
The mentionned in other topic solution is not what asked for.
And I went to the better one which should be useful for other users.

Comment: Edit the first 55314063 lines out of the input file, leaving in the last INSERT line of course

Comment: This questions has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333018/how-to-import-sql-file-to-database-ignoring-x-lines-in-file/19035324

Comment: The question was asked, but the solution is not what I asked for. I don't know why topic starter accepted it.

Comment: If the linked question does not help to resolve your problem, please provide more details

Comment: The answer accepted there "try to import mysql file with -f to ignore the errors" is not the answer to the question asked. 
I don't know why this has been accepted. 
The one below "You can use tail" is actually right, though I used slightly different syntax. 
And the main conclusion - if you can - just do it again,  other solutions aren't complete and you spend even more your time trying to save some computer time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping to line 55314064+1 and resuming will not do what you think. There may be lines prior to that that also need to be executed, for example to `USE` the right schema. Also to set a number of session variables.

You should also figure out *why* it disconnected from the MySQL server. Otherwise it will just happen again if you try to resume the import.

A common reason for this error during an import is that you have some SQL statement that is larger than `max_allowed_packet`. You need to make sure both client (`mysql`) and server can handle the length of data in a single SQL statement that you are trying to import. For example if you are trying to import a large TEXT or BLOB field.

The default for `max_allowed_packet` is 64MB in recent versions of MySQL. But you can easily have a line in your import file that tries to insert a larger value.

There are other reasons why the same error could occur. I just described one of the common reasons that happens during an import. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: I know why it was disconnected. 
Being busy in other session I restarted mysqld service while completely forgotten that there is a import proces.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would do it! :-) Anyway, to be honest, I would just restart the import from scratch. I would want to be sure I didn't skip too much and miss some important data.

Comment: You are right. 
I managed to resume the import (pity that the topic is closed , otherwise I'd share it) 
But it takes also time and doesn't provide 100% reliability, 
So it was (in my case) better just to redo it.